# Where to find the access token stored in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

Is there a way to find all the access tokens stored in google analytic's dashboard. And is it possible to fetch all the active access tokens ?

Comment: By dashboard do you mean website?   If so then NO you cant get access to other users access tokens.

Comment: even being admin of our app ?

Comment: If you mean www.google.com/analytics/.  No you are not admin of that you cant have access to other peoples access.   If you gave them access to your Google Analytics account in the admin section then they can see it.  But you cant access there access tokens

Comment: ok. considering your point itself, how can they see? could you plz explain where exactly those access tokens are present in www.google.com/analytics/ itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics dashboard **www.google.com/analytics/** does not store access tokens that it will give you.    The only way for you to know who has been granted access to your Google Analytics account is to check the admin section for the Google Analytics Account.

> Top of the page Admin -> account -> user management.

Access tokens are used for Authentication.  If the Google Analytics webpage uses them which it probably does.  It is not something that Google will share with you.   You would have no use for it anyway as access tokens are created by a key par using the client id , client secret.  You do not have access to Google's client id and client secret.  so could not use an access token.   Also access tokens are only good for an hour.

I don't understand why you would even want to see Googles access tokens you cant use them.

Comment: Thanks for your Kind Reply @DalmTo, i can't accept this answer except an vote up. I am wondering, what if their is a way to break the link of an user by deleting the access token in google analytics... hope you got what i am thinking of...

Comment: No they can just log in again.  Once you have added a user to Google analytics they have access.

Comment: If their is no chance of accessing access_tokens, i probably think my question itself doesn't suits for the feasibility of google's law of analytics ;) :P. So that ill have to accept your answer. Last Question: Is their a way to create user and assign permissions for my app dynamically as i have created 3 users for test case manually. I think of scopes could play some bit of role here if i am not wrong. Correct me plz

Comment: Are you trying to give more users access to your google analytics account?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileUserLinks/insert

Comment: yup exactly for our vendors

Comment: Management api gives you access to add users to different accounts.